# Why do I get a null object reference error when trying to make a button visible after long pressing on a recycler view item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a button visible when a user long clicks on a row in the recycler view. However I'm getting a null object reference error and not sure why. The Toast works so I know that the long press is working on each row.

Edit - Crash Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.it_stock, PID: 13959
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.it_stock.StockAdapter$ViewHolder.onLongClick(StockAdapter.java:85)
        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:5714)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5672)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5690)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:22402)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DBHandler db;
    Button btnAddItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView stockView = findViewById(R.id.rvStock);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        stockView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        stockView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        db = new DBHandler(this);
        ArrayList<Stock> allStock = db.getAllStock();

        if (allStock.size() > 0) {
            stockView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            StockAdapter stockAdapter = new StockAdapter(this, allStock);
            stockView.setAdapter(stockAdapter);
        }
        else {
            stockView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Items!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        btnAddItem = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            addNewItem();
        });
    }

    protected void addNewItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewItem.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class StockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StockAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Stock> listStock;
    private ArrayList<Stock> mArrayList;
    private DBHandler db;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    StockAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stock> listStock) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listStock = listStock;
        this.mArrayList = listStock;
        db = new DBHandler(context);
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View stockView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(stockView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Stock stock = listStock.get(position);
        holder.tvItem.setText(stock.getItem());
        holder.tvCondition.setText(stock.getCondition());
        holder.tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(stock.getQuantity()));
        holder.tvLocation.setText(stock.getLocation());
        holder.tvCategory.setText(stock.getCategory());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listStock.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        final TextView tvItem;
        final TextView tvCondition;
        final TextView tvQuantity;
        final TextView tvLocation;
        final TextView tvCategory;
        Button btnRemove;
        View stockView;

        ViewHolder(View stockView) {
            super(stockView);
            this.stockView = stockView;
            stockView.setOnClickListener(this);
            stockView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            tvItem = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            tvCondition = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvCondition);
            tvQuantity = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
            tvLocation = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvCategory = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            btnRemove = stockView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View stockView) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View stockView) {
            btnRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The button should appear just below the recycler view in activity_main and I have set this up in my xml file and set the button to 'invisible'. Please can someone explain why I'm getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: `btnRemove` is present in  `stock_row` or it is present in `activity_main`? . Please attach your crash logs also

Comment: Share your logcat, exactly where you got null object.

Comment: @Nitish It's in activity_main, I've edited the body to include this and the crash log - thanks.

Comment: `btnRemove` is null , you are find the button from view `stockView` , while in actual your button never exits there , it's in main activity . To fix this find the id of button in `MainActivity` and give a call back from recycler adapter to activity using interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `btnRemove` is null it means `stockView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove)`
returns null so it means there is no View with id `btnRemove` in `R.layout.stock_row`

check if you have this line in `R.layout.stock_row` :

```
android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had it in activity_main. This makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code like this, you have initialize listeners before the button.

```
ViewHolder(View stockView) {
            super(stockView);
            this.stockView = stockView;
            tvItem = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            tvCondition = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvCondition);
            tvQuantity = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
            tvLocation = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvCategory = stockView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            btnRemove = stockView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
            stockView.setOnClickListener(this);
            stockView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }
```